# Profile ID not stored in User after creation Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote the following code:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

@login_required(login_url="/login")
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            profile = Profile().save() 
            user = form
            user.profile = profile
            user.save()

            return redirect('users')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    user_model = get_user_model()
    users = user_model.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(users, 15) 

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    users = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, 'users/index.html', {'users': users, 'form': form})

class Profile(models.Model):
    has_premium_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    has_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    has_telegram_premium_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    has_telegram_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

When I'm submitting the form the user as well as the profile is created but the profile is not stored in the user (the profile_id stays null).

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: You are assigning user to a form, and then assigning profile to it. Therefore, you are assigning a profile to a form instance, which doesn't have a profile field. That is why your code doesn't save a profile field

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov The same happens why I add the profile field in the Meta of the form class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
    if form.is_valid():

        profile = Profile().save() 
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.profile = profile
        user.save()

        return redirect('users')
```

This way the user object will be created and then you refer to the profile ju just created and save it.

There is however another way of doing it with signals:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_profile_on_user_reg(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.profile = Profile()
        instance.save()
```

Check out more on [Django signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/)